# JSON.NET: How to Serialize Nested Collections

Tags: c#, json.net

This is driving me nuts... I am serializing a List to JSON using Json.net. I expect this JSON:

```
{
    "fieldsets": [
        {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "alias": "date",
                    "value": "2014-02-12T00:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "alias": "time",
                    "value": null
                }
            ],
            "alias": "eventDates",
            "disabled": false
        }
    ]
}
```

But instead I get this:

```
{
    "fieldsets": [
        {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "alias": "date",
                            "value": "2014-07-13T00:00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "alias": "time",
                            "value": "Registration begins at 8:00 AM; walk begins at 9:00 AM"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "alias": "eventDates",
            "disabled": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The "values" collection I'd like as just a JSON array, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to do this. I have a property on my "properties" objects called "values", so I understand why it's doing it, but I need just the straight array, not a JSON object.

Comment: Lets see the object definition for the object you're serializing.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ Go wild

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For that response, you need this class structure

```
public class Property
{
    [JsonProperty("alias")]
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Fieldset
{
    [JsonProperty("properties")]
    public Property[] Properties { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("alias")]
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("disabled")]
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("fieldsets")]
    public Fieldset[] Fieldsets { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is very close except I'm getting back something strange on the "properties" array... It's outputting twice, once with "properties" and once with "Properties":

Comment: Nevermind... I had a JsonProperty attribute in the wrong place... This works! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! Spent almost all day trying to get this right. :-/

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be the answer:

```
public class Property
{
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Fieldset
{
    public List<Property> properties { get; set; }
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public bool disabled { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Fieldset> fieldsets { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you just post what json2csharp.com gave you?

Comment: Well, for one thing you can't use a default get/set on a List<t> but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to JObject:

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(myJsonString);
```

Navigation by key:

```
jsonObject["property"]["value"];//Property is value / object
jsonObject["value"];
```

Navigation by index:

```
jsonObject[0]["value"]; // Property is array / list
jsonObject[0];
```