# Save an Array of Objects in a json object

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

So I have two c# classes (Team and Player) and I want to store a team into a json file. Every team has some players. I think it should look like this:

```
{
    "name":"Chelsea"
    "players": [
        {
            "name":"Player1"
        },
        {
            "name":"Player2"
        },
        {
            "name":"Player3"
        }
    ]
}
```

But sadly it isn't working for me. It always only returns:

```
{"name":"Chelsea"}
```

I do not really know why this happens. Is it even possible to do this?
My code is:

```
public class Team
{
    public string name = "testTeam";
    public Player[] players = new Player[0];

    public void AddPlayer(Player player)
    {
        int i = players.Length;
        players = new Player[i+1];
        players[i] = player;
    }

    public void save()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/data/teams/" + name + ".json", JsonUtility.ToJson(this));
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public string name;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808718/json-net-how-to-serialize-nested-collections

Comment: thx I will take a look at this!

Comment: Check out the Unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html). It especially has a note regarding arrays.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy This post is not really about what my problem is. I can't even save an array in json, in the post the array is just saved in a wrong way

Comment: @ErikT. You're right so I can't use this method, but I do not know an alternative to this ... any ideas?

Comment: You could use Newtonsoft.json instead of the class provided by unity. Check [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) out.

Comment: thx I'll give it a try

Comment: @atiyar  The expected output as well as the actual output is given in the question. So it's not vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Serialization Rules](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)

> **How to ensure a custom class can be serialized**
>
> Ensure it:
>
> - **Has the `[Serializable]` attribute**
> - Is not abstract
> - Is not static
> - Is not generic, though it may inherit from a generic class
>
> To ensure the fields of a custom class or struct are serialized, see How to ensure a field in a script is serialized, above.

You should add the Attribute [`[Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute)

```
[Serializable]
public class Team
{
    ...
}

[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    ...
}
```

A very good hint which things will be correctly serialized by Unity's built-in JsonUtility gives the Inspector since it uses the same serialization rules.

Just put somewhere a

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Team team;
}
```

and you will see if it is correctly serialized or not in the Inspector in Unity.

---

Then also see [Jawad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65812262/7111561) answer for an optimized way for dynamically storing entries ;)

---

As a fallback for a more powerful JSON library with less restrictions you can always switch to the [Newtonsoft Json.NET Unity package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.0/manual/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems I see with your code is,

```
public Player[] players = new Player[0];

public void AddPlayer(Player player)
{
    int i = players.Length;
    players = new Player[i+1];
    players[i] = player;
}
```

Each time you add a player, you throw away the old players and only add new player to the end of the array.

Instead of array, I believe `List` would suite you best in this case,

```
public List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

public void AddPlayer(Player player)
{
    players.Add(player);
}
```

For serialization, (as per @derHugo 's recommendation), add the [Serializable] Attribute  to your class.

```
[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public string name;
}
...
```

Comment: Oh I am stupid... thanks I didn't think enough xD